# JSON Converter problem VBA. How to make this useable?

Tags: json, excel, vba, salesforce

I'm using JSON converter API to convert JSON data from salesforce, but it does not seems to work for me.
https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

I'm getting correct JSON data in "GetReport(ReportId, SessionId, ReportMetadataJson"
[image]
But when I use converter

```
Set Report = JsonConverter.ParseJson(GetReport(ReportId, SessionId, ReportMetadataJson))

Dim Rows As Object
Dim Columns As Object
Dim ColumnInfo
 
Set Columns = Report("reportMetadata")("detailColumns")
Set ColumnInfo = Report("reportExtendedMetadata")("detailColumnInfo")
Set Rows = Report("factMap")("T!T")("rows")

Dim Total_Rows As Long: Total_Rows = Rows.Count
```

It gives me Rows.Count = 0 every time, which is not correct. Please can you help?

cannot find solution on the internet

Comment: With `report("factMap")("11_0_0!T")("rows")` I get a count of 1 as per your screenshot

Comment: Thanks!!! It looks like "T!T" was the problem, now I'm getting my data in correct format

Comment: I need to learn more about factMap, Cheers